# How to find element with 'contains', 'text' using css selector in selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I could have found xpath and jquery selector using 'contains' but can't find text using 'contains' or 'text' in css selector. What is the keyword similar to 'contains' in css selector?

Answer (score 1):

its not possible in css selector..you have to use xpath for contains text

Comment: This is not true. You can use CSS selector with contains, but use plugin extension to evaluate it. For example a:contains('Terms') works fine on https://wordpress.com/log-in using CSS Selector Tester plugin in chrome.